# Add character to an existing column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an img column and there is thousands rows.

```
id   img
1     test.j
2     test2.j
```

I want to change the value to

```
id   img
1    test.jpg
2    test2.jpg
```

How can i do this in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET img=CONCAT(img,'pg')
```

Reference:

- [CONCAT(str1,str2,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [13.2.10 UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)